# How can I turn a string with style information into Text Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example, I have a string:

```
"Wherefor art <strong>thou</strong> mr. <strong>fancypants</strong>"
```

I need to turn this into react-native Text components and back to a render() method.  So the string would be transformed into:

```
<Text>Where for art <Text style={{ fontweight : 600}}>thou</Text> mr. <Text style={{fontweight: 600}}>fancypants</Text>;
```

So my render method looks like this:

```
render() {
  let text = "Wherefor art <strong>thou</strong> mr. <strong>fancypants</strong>";
  return (
    <View style={{marginBottom : 20}}>
      <Text>{this.filterHtml(text)}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

And what I tried for turning text into components, which obviously doesn't work:

```
filterHtml = (text) => {
  if (text) {
    return text.replace(/<strong>([^<]*)<\/strong>/g, "<Text style={{fontweight : 600}}>$1</Text>")
  }
  return text;
}
```

Not surprisingly what ends up happening is this literal string being rendered inside the `<Text>` element as shown in the render method:

```
"Where for art <Text style={{ fontweight : 600}}>thou</Text> mr. <Text style={{fontweight: 600}}>fancypants".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do it the other way around: instead of replacing <strong> with <Text />, build a component which finds the strings between <strong> tags and passes them to the <Text  /> with the rest in between.

For example: "Hey <strong> Hi </strong> Hoi" would be:

"Hey" <Text> "Hi" </Text> "Hoi"

Comment: @leo That's exactly what I'm wondering how to do.  Likely some kind of text.split().map() returning <Text> elements styled only when <strong> is found.

Comment: My point is only - you shouldn't start with a string replace with <Text />. You should start with <Text /> and put in string - that's the only way. You will figure it out - it's not that trivial, but brute force should work (somehow:P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked how to split into multiple text components but it sounds like your end goal is to display html appropriately.  If that is truly the case check out [react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview).  If that is not your intent you can at least see how they tackled this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A not-very-good solution: Use the HTML function in the [Webview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html). So something like:

```
<WebView
 source={{html:text}}
  />
```

This has some drawbacks though: You can't style the Webview according to the content height. If this doesn't matter to you - you're in luck.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider a webview but for the consideration you mentioned, and others, it's not really on the table.

Comment: fair enough - then I'm curious for other answers, since I faced this problem fairly recently. 
maybe this one helps: https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview

Comment: it did indeed help!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<Text>
  <Text>Where for art </Text>
  <Text style={{ fontweight : 600}}>thou</Text>
  <Text>mr. </Text>
  <Text style={{fontweight: 600}}>fancypants</Text>
</Text>
```

The react native documentation clearly says that Text can be nested.

> Text supports nesting, styling, and touch handling.

Comment: But the question is, how to best parse a string and return react text elements to be rendered in the render() method?  The question I ask already specifies that I desire nested <Text> tags.  But starting with a string...